# Проблема в отправке запроса API Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет! Я использую Telegram Api и отправляю простейший запрос

```
accsess_token = ...
headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apn g,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b2',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 
         Safari/537.36'
}
str_query = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{accsess_token}/getMe'
resp = requests.get(str_query, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
print(resp)
```

Дальше запускается скрипт.. думает долго и тут:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/bot1051933687:{accsess_token}/getMe (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object 
at 0x7f8895a68278>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Далее я решил использовать прокси,соответственно,изменения в коде произошли такие

```
proxies = {
    'https': '163.172.182.164:3128',
}

resp = requests.get(str_query,headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

Пробовал много прокси-серверов.. и у всех один ответ.. правда теперь скрипт отрабатывает быстро,точнее ошибка вылетает сразу же, а не как в первом случае,когда скрипт "думал" долго

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max 
retries exceeded with url: /bot1051933687:{accsess_token}/getMe (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))
```

Подскажите, моя проблема в том что я так и не добрался до рабочего прокси или тут что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательнее читайте документацию!

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'socks5://54.38.195.161:55155',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phone'])){
  if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])){
  $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
  $nameFieldset = "Имя пославшего: ";
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['phone'])){
  $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
  $phoneFieldset = "Телефон: ";
  }
}
if (isset($_POST['theme'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['theme'])){
  $theme = strip_tags($_POST['theme']);
  $themeFieldset = "Тема:";
  }
}
$token = "";
$chat_id = "";
$arr = array(
  $nameFieldset => $name,
  $phoneFieldset => $phone,

);
    $txt = ''; 
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {

  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
if ($sendToTelegram) {

  echo '<p class="success" style="color: #18d26e";>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>';
    return true;
} else {
  echo '<p class="fail"  style="color: red";><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></p>';
}
} else {
  echo '<p class="fail" style="color: red";>Ошибка. Вы заполнили не все обязательные поля!</p>';
}
} else {
echo '<p class="success" style="color: #18d26e";>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!</p>';
}

?>


/////////////////////////////

AJAX

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-element").submit(function () {
        var formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formNm = $('#' + formID);
        var message = $(formNm).find(".form-message");
        var formTitle = $(formNm).find(".form-title");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: './telegramform/php/send-message-to-telegram.php',
            data: formNm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              // Вывод сообщения об успешной отправке
              message.html(data);
              formTitle.css("display","none");
              setTimeout(function(){
                formTitle.css("display","block");
                message.html('');
                $('input').not(':button[type=submit], :button[type=hidden]').val('');
              }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод сообщения об ошибке отправки
                message.html(error);
                formTitle.css("display","none");
                setTimeout(function(){
                  formTitle.css("display","block");
                  message.html('');
                  $('button').not(':button[type=submit], :button[type=hidden]').val('');
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Вы уверены,  в том,  что вы точно поняли мой вопрос?

Comment: Я просто дал готовый код,  чтобы вы не парились со старым

Comment: Ну во-первых, обратите внимание на метки, там стоит метка python. Вы предлагаете пример php кода. Во-вторых, ваш ответ - это не решение проблемы.

Comment: тогда прошу простить, просто хотел помочь)